# Load Images in Modal after it's fired

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want the images to load when the modal is opened NOT when the page loads.  I have this script but it's not working.  Meaning it doesn't load the actual image but rather the wait image only. But it's loading the wait image because of the image code, look below.

```
    function loadImagesToModal(){
     $('img[src="img/port/wait-images.jpg"]').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).attr('src', $(el).data('real-src'));
    });
    }
     $({.portfolio-modal}).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    loadImagesToModal();
    })


<img class="img-fluid" src="img/port/wait-images.jpg" data-real-src="img/port/the-real-image.jpg" alt="">
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong please?

**-------- UPDATE --------**

I've decided to use the Yall plugin.   Giovan Cruz said to try a plugin so I did-thank you.  It works far as changing the images from load image to the real image.  But it still loads the images on page load.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
<script src="yall-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", yall);</script>
<img class="lazy" src="img/placeholder.jpg" data-src="img/image-to-lazy-load.jpg">
```

**-------- UPDATE 2 --------**

It works!!!! I ended up using the yall plugin.  Added the code above and all works now.

Comment: What is that syntax: $({.portfolio - modal})? Anyway, if you want, take a look in lazyLoad imgs plugins

Comment: Not sure I copied it from the web.  What's it's suppose to be?  $('.portfolio - modal')?

Comment: Yep, without white spaces, because this is an DOM selector: `$('.portfolio-modal')` and this is the custom bootstrap event you want to watch: .on('shown.bs.modal'. You must have the element `clas="portfolio-modal"` in your HTML. When 'shown' is binded your function will execute.

Comment: Thanks.  I added that and still doesn't display the image in the modal.  I added the image code to images outside of the modal and it works.  For some reason, in the modal, it doesn't work.  Can you see a reason why?

Comment: Can you please share more details of your code? Make a codepen / jsfiddle with it? Or edit your question and make a snippet code

Comment: I added an update.  I actually took your advice to use a plugin.  You can read the rest in the update.  Thanks

Comment: It works now.  Thanks for your help.  If there's away I can give you credit for the plugin idea let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: Credit is yours by research, Glad it worked!